# Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: context/Dockerfile - Pipeline Bitbucket

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to setup a bitbucket pipeline for my React project. I created a docker-compose file and a Dockerfile for this purpose.

Here is my pipeline file :

```
  branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          name: Dockerize
          script:
            - docker login $DOCKER_REGISTRY -u $DOCKER_REGISTRY_LOGIN -p $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PWD
            - docker build -f context/Dockerfile -t $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME --build-arg BASE_API_URL=$API_DEV_URL .
            - docker tag $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$BITBUCKET_COMMIT
            - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$BITBUCKET_COMMIT
          services:
            - docker
          caches:
            - docker
      - step:
          name: Deploy to dev
          deployment: dev
          script:
            - ssh -p $SERVER_PORT $SERVER_USER@$SERVER rm -Rf $DOCKER_COMPOSE_DEV_PATH/*
            - ssh -p $SERVER_PORT $SERVER_USER@$SERVER mkdir $DOCKER_COMPOSE_DEV_PATH/log
            - scp -P $SERVER_PORT docker-compose.yml $SERVER_USER@$SERVER:$DOCKER_COMPOSE_DEV_PATH/
            - ssh -p $SERVER_PORT $SERVER_USER@$SERVER docker pull $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$BITBUCKET_COMMIT
            - ssh -p $SERVER_PORT $SERVER_USER@$SERVER docker tag $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$BITBUCKET_COMMIT $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$BITBUCKET_COMMIT
            - ssh -p $SERVER_PORT $SERVER_USER@$SERVER docker rmi $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$BITBUCKET_COMMIT
            - ssh -p $SERVER_PORT $SERVER_USER@$SERVER TAG=$BITBUCKET_COMMIT docker-compose -p container-name -f $DOCKER_COMPOSE_DEV_PATH/docker-compose.yml down
            - ssh -p $SERVER_PORT $SERVER_USER@$SERVER TAG=$BITBUCKET_COMMIT docker-compose -p container-name -f $DOCKER_COMPOSE_DEV_PATH/docker-compose.yml up -d

options:
  docker: true
```

Here is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  image_name:
    image: repo/image_name:${TAG}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: context/Dockerfile
      args:
        - BASE_API_URL=${BASE_API_URL}
    volumes:
      - ./log:/var/log/nginx/
```

My files tree is as follow

```
-app
|_ bitbucket-pipeline.yml
|_ docker-compose.yml
|_ context
  |_ Dockerfile
```

From what I read, I don't see the problem with my docker-compose file. My context and dockerfile reference should work. But I end up having an error `Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: context/Dockerfile` at the last step of my pipeline (i.e when running the docker-compose up command)

I don't know what I should change to make it work.

Comment: what is the value of `$DOCKER_COMPOSE_DEV_PATH` ?

Comment: A path on my server

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
docker build -f context/Dockerfile -t $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME --build-arg BASE_API_URL=$API_DEV_URL ./context
```